# is it possible to convert a string to varbinary in PHP without using the SQL function

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I was wondering if it is possible to convert a string to varbinary with PHP to get the same effect as with using the SQL function `CONVERT(varbinary, 'data')` I would like to do this because I am using codeigniter and would like to use active records for this query, and because of this not directly use a string of SQL, but I need to insert the data into a varbinary field in MS-SQL.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can cast a string as a binary if you are using a recent enough version of PHP.

```
$binary = (binary)$string;
```

(binary) casting and b prefix forward support was added in PHP 5.2.1

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 3):

```
public static function str2bin($str) { 
  return '0x'.strtoupper(bin2hex($str));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Till, this helped me immensely when converting the other way. `$data = hex2bin(substr($data, 2));`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, but it returns me a binary value as a string.  Is there any way around this as I need a raw binary value to insert into a database, not varchar.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the pack function

example
convert {326546, 4356345, 43646346, 366357547} to var-binary as Unsigned int

> $_BIN=pack('I*', 326546, 4356345, 43646346, 366357547);

you can find more examples at 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php