# Convert string to Varbinary in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, odbc

I have the following code in php:

```
$salt = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(22));
$hash = crypt($this->input->post("defpswd"), "$2y$12$".$salt);
```

If i try to save $hash value to a MSSQL database table with a varbinary datatype field, i get the error message:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Implicit conversion
>   from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT
>   function to run this query.

$hash variable contains:

> '$2y$12$35695d29f921c713eba4fu1VY0q6VF6HryPH9HjiLvHOoupXWvPn.'

If i cast $hash by using binary as in [is it possible to convert a string to varbinary in PHP without using the SQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636712/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-string-to-varbinary-in-php-without-using-the-sql-fun) i get the same error. 
I am using CodeIgniter and MSSQL database with an odbc connection. What is it that i am not getting right? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`$hash` is not binary it is a character string, it has been Base64 encoded and Base64 is a character (ASCII). Just use the `varchar` DB type.

There is no reason to cast it to `varbinary`.

Comment: I am trying to use an existing database with the table field type being varbinary. I cant change the field type. Thank you for your response.

Comment: That seems like a decision that will be troublesome and hated for years to come. Kind of like a pair of shows a little to narrow and short.

Comment: Its really a troublesome decision

Comment: Do the "right thing", you know what that is and the future will thank you.